Replay type fluid simulation not working as expected. What am I doing wrong?
Replay type fluid simulation not working as expected.
Hello everyone, I am following a tutorial from a book, on fluid simulation. I am expecting the simulation to have been baked after the first run and should be replaying on subsequent runs using the Timeline editor.
This is not the case as the frame rate of subsequent runs is the same (as that of the first run as you will see in the screenshot which is one of the subsequent runs and still running at a 0.78 fps).
I am assuming that the cause of the low frame rate is that the subsequent runs are redoing the calculation, hence the simulation is not baked. From the blender manual,
Type
...
Replay
The cache will be baked as the simulation is being played in the viewport...
My Question: I assume this means that the first run already did the baking, what could I be doing wrong that makes the subsequent play in the timeline to redo the baking?


it is only baked if you hit the "bake" button, else it is "just" cached. So if you change anything in between - Blender calculates again and it will be slow again. The difference is: if you change anything after you hit the bake button, you will see the "old simulation". If you make changes, they won't be considered until you hit the bake button again.

@Chris I played it repeatedly without changing anything. Does that mean that it recalculates even when nothing is changed?
